# How to get around Instgram oauth failures after they enforced sandbox mode?

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I have been using Instagram API on my website for a year now and it worked 
perfectly until today when they [enforced the sandbox mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) on all applications. Now I get an oAuth error on any request that I make with my client-id. Even simple requests like the following:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&client_id=[CLIENTID]
```

How do I get around this problem? I have checked that I am not calling for more than 20 most recent media in my API calls as suggested by the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Instagram API changelog

> All API endpoints require a valid access_token

You need to authorise a user with your app. Even the Instagram account you registered the client with you need to follow their authentication steps here [Instagram API authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Note that in Sandbox mode only other sandbox users will be visible. I.E if you try and get recent media for UserA who is not a sandbox users, it will come up as no user found.

Comment: I overlooked this change. Thanks for pointing it out. As a follow up question, the documentation says that the access tokens may expire anytime in the future. Does that mean that I will have to get a new access token by re-authorizing myself every time the token expires?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. We have seen a few cases where the token gets revoked. When a user revokes it from their profile and when they use things like follow for follow apps. Certain behaviour seems to flag an account as spam and requires the user to enter a capcha when they sign in. This seems to revoke all tokens from their account.

Answer (score 4):

you can fetch the photos using
https://www.instagram.com/[USERNAME]/media/

With this you can get the latest 20 posts.
If you are using php, the code would look like:

```
$instaResult= file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/media/')
$insta = json_decode($instaResult);
```